# Cómo hacer un main en Ruby

Tags: ruby

Estoy aprendiendo Ruby y es la primera vez que hago un programa con clases en este lenguaje.

Me queda hacer el `main`, pero no sé por dónde empezar

Comment: No se entiende tu preguntra amigo, ¿a qué te refieres con un main?

Comment: Quiero hacer la función main, es decir, el programa principal donde utilizar las clases. Por ejemplo en c++ tenemos int main()

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que en C++ y en Java por ejemplo el método `main` es el punto de inicialización del código; me parece en Ruby varía un poco; pues tenemos que por cada archivo declaramos una clase con sus métodos y atributos y estos mismos serán leídos interpretados y ejecutados de manera secuencial.

Clase **Padre.rb**

```
class Padre

  def mensaje
    puts "Soy tu padre SO en español :D"
  end

end
```

Creamos nuestra primer instancia, que puede estar contenido en el mismo archivo o en otro.

```
padre1 = Padre.new()
padre1.mensaje()
```

Lo que nos dará como resultado:

> Soy tu padre SO en español :D

Entonces como puedes observar lo que va a ocurrir es que el código se leera desde la declaración de la clase, pero mostrará algún resultado en pantalla hasta que lea la línea donde se realiza la instancia de la clase asignada al objeto `padre1`

**Sin embargo....**

Para el caso de C++, citando a la página cplusplus.com<sup>1</sup> no importa el orden de los métodos declarados en un programa en C++, siempre el método que se invocará primero es el `main`

Como puedes observar en este ejemplo<sup>2</sup> tomado de la misma página:

```
// classes example
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {
    int width, height;
  public:
    void set_values (int,int);
    int area() {return width*height;}
};

void Rectangle::set_values (int x, int y) {
  width = x;
  height = y;
}

int main () {
  Rectangle rect;
  rect.set_values (3,4);
  cout << "area: " << rect.area();
  return 0;
}
```

El método `main` donde se invoca a la clase `Rectangle` y al objeto `rect` donde primero accedemos al método que setea los valores para calcular el área y luego invoca al método área para obtener el resultado de dicho cálculo.

Una aproximación al mismo ejercicio en Ruby pudiera ser de este modo:

```
class Rectangle
  def initialize(width, height)
    @width = width
    @height = height
  end

  def area
    puts @width * @height
  end
end


rect = Rectangle.new(3, 4)
rect.area();
```

**Explicación**

- Declaramos una clase de nombre `Rectangle`
- Creamos un método constructor<sup>3</sup> que será el primero en ser llamado una vez que la clase sea instanciada a un nuevo objeto
- Dentro del método constructor pasamos como argumentos 2 propiedades que serán requeridas de darles valores al momento de instanciar la clase a un nuevo objeto
- Creamos un método `area` que procesará multiplicando los valores que reciba la clase
- En el objeto `rect` creamos la instancia de la clase y le pasamos 2 valores a los argumentos declarados dentro de la clase en el método constructor
- Con el objeto `rect` accedemos al método `area` que nos debería imprimir **12**

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup>[método `main` en C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/)
- <sup>2</sup>[clases en C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/)
- <sup>3</sup>[método `initialize`](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/UsersGuide/rg/objinitialization.html)

Comment: Esta respuesta me sirvió para darme cuenta de lo malo que soy en C++

Comment: Me gustaría mucho leer una respuesta de @PaperBirdMaster